# Perl TCP, print, select, and sysread - buffering behavior

Tags: perl, tcp, buffer

The client:

```
$socket->autoflush(1);
print $socket "abel\n";
print $socket "baker\n";
print $socket "charlie\n";
```

My question:

When the server's `select()` (or `can_read`) completes, what guarantees do I have about the contents of the system `receive` buffer?  Is it possible for it to contain a single "a"?  Or "abel\nbak"?  Or is the system buffer *guaranteed* to contain exactly one, two, or all three of the strings that were sent from corresponding 'print' statements in the client?

This obviously has implications about how I manage the application-level buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such guarantees with TCP (and SOCK_STREAM in general). Anything you listed is possible.

Comment: I suspected as much.  Is there, by chance, a Perl module that implements select() at a higher level, indicating that a complete line-end-terminated string can be retrieved without blocking?  Or do I have to manage that myself?

Comment: I don't know Perl, but e.g. in TCL, we put sockets in non-blocking mode and use normal `gets` (i.e. high-level read-line function). If the line is incomplete, it just returns "nothing" (with a flag), but the partial line stays buffered. So we just have to "select" again when "gets" failed. Perl must have something equivalent.

Comment: I'm almost positive it does; I just never knew what it was for.  Thanks - you've answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees. "a" and "abel\nbak" are both possible.

`sysread` won't block if there's data available; it will return what's available. As such, you can use

```
for my $fh (@ready) {
   my $close = 0;
   my $client = $clients{$fh};

   our $buf; local *buf = $client->{buf};
   my $rv = sysread($buf, 0, 64*1024, length($buf)); 
   if ($rv) {
      while ($buf =~ s/^(.*)\n//) {
         my $msg = $1;
         $close = 1 if process_msg($msg);
      }
   } else {
      $close = 1;
      # Handle error and eof here.
   }

   if ($close) {
      $readers->delete($fh);
      delete $clients->{$fh};
   }
}
```